# Multiple conditions (equal & like ) on the same column with conditions in another column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-like

Problem is how to put both `like` or "equal" conditions in one column with mixing the others conditions in different columns

My goal:

```
select *
from TABLE
where A_column like 'A%' 
  and B_column = '5' 
  and C_column like 'SH%' or = 'SY_0005'    -- like & equal in one column
```

I cannot use `REGEX_LIKE` by just doing:

```
select *
from TABLE
where A_column like 'A%' 
  and B_column = '5' 
  and REGEXP_LIKE(C_column, '^(SH|SY_0005)')
```

What is the equivalent way to perform it in SQL Server?

Comment: `C_column LIKE 'SH%' OR C_column = 'SY_0005'` is the best you can do in SQL Server, unless you want to use a regex UDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from TABLE
where A_column like 'A%' AND B_column = '5' AND
(C_column like 'SH%' or C_column = 'SY_0005')
```